# Google Tag Manager - Google Analytics Purchase Sending Requests Multiple Times

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to setup Google Analytics 4 Conversion with google tag manager. When I setup all events are working fine except the purchase event. The add to cart, begin checkout, view item all work fine but the purchase event is counted multiple times and requesting multiple times.[my website](https://isternet.com/) [Google tag manager screenshoot when i trigged purchase event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43kMg.png)

When I tried it on a wordpress site with the same method, there was no problem. My current site is a site coded with php.  I'm waiting for your help.

I did try setup conversions with google tag manager.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your trigger is based on custom `event : purchase`

So you need to investigate why there are so many datalayer event is `purchase`

You can look into every purchase event and what is inside the datalayer.

Best of the case is you can understand where it came from and make it only push one time.

Comment: How can I check if I have pushed the datalayer more than once?